# What is the Tkinter eval() function?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am currently building a calculator in Tkinter. I've been searching a few youtube videos to define a few functions and I came across this:

```
result = eval(self.string.get())
```

I understand that it is creating a new variable called `result` that holds the contents of `string.get()`, but I am unsure what `eval()` does.

Comment: First step before asking a question should be to consult the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval

Comment: http://lybniz2.sourceforge.net/safeeval.html 
not quite sure but it says "lets a python program run python code within itself"

Answer (score 1):

This takes the string as an expression and determines its value.  For instance, the string "3 + 5" would return 8.