# My calculator doesn't work, it doesn't print the result on the screen

Tags: python, tkinter, calculator

So my problem is that my calculator works normally, it shows the operation that I am writing, but when I click on the " equal ", the result isn't here. I don't know why, because in the code, I have written the good things, so I am stuck. If someone could help me, I would be very happy. Thanks.

The code :

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time

window = Tk()
window.title("Calculatrice")
window.geometry("250x350")
window.configure(bg="cyan")

Canvaswidth = 250
Canvasheight = 350

canvas = Canvas(window, width=Canvaswidth, height=Canvasheight, bg="cyan")
canvas.pack()

# Optionnel

remplirBas = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 299, 250, 350, fill="#023e8a")

crédits = Label(canvas, text="Calculatrice créée par Tresda28", font=("Segoe print", 10), bg="#023e8a", fg="#0077b6")
crédits.place(x=15, y=310)

# Opérations

opération = 0
nombre = int()

def Bouton1():
    global nombre
    nombre = 1
    output.config(text=nombre)

def Bouton2():
    global nombre
    nombre = 2
    output.config(text=nombre)

def Bouton3():
    global nombre
    nombre = 3
    output.config(text=nombre)

def Bouton4():
    global nombre
    nombre = 4
    output.config(text=nombre)

def Bouton5():
    global nombre
    nombre = 5
    output.config(text=nombre)

def Bouton6():
    global nombre
    nombre = 6
    output.config(text=nombre)

def Bouton7():
    global nombre
    nombre = 7
    output.config(text=nombre)

def Bouton8():
    global nombre
    nombre = 8
    output.config(text=nombre)

def Bouton9():
    global nombre
    nombre = 9
    output.config(text=nombre)

# Fonctions opérateurs

def BoutonPlus():
    global opération, nombre
    opération = opération + nombre

def BoutonMoins():
    global opération, nombre
    opération = opération - nombre

def BoutonFois():
    global opération, nombre
    opération = opération * nombre

def BoutonDivisé():
    global opération, nombre
    opération = opération / nombre

"""def BoutonVirgule():
    global opération, nombre
    opération = opération"""

def BoutonEgal():
    global opération, nombre
    opération = result
    output.config(text=result)
    window.update()

def Quitter():
    canvas.forget()
    window.destroy()

# Opérateurs

boutonPlus = Button(canvas, text=" + ", font=("Courrier", 23), bg="#0077b6", fg="white", command=BoutonPlus)
boutonPlus.place(x=128, y=0)

boutonMoins = Button(canvas, text=" - ", font=("Courrier", 23), bg="#0077b6", fg="white")
boutonMoins.place(x=192, y=0)

boutonFois = Button(canvas, text=" * ", font=("Courrier", 26), bg="#0077b6", fg="white")
boutonFois.place(x=128, y=62)

boutonDivisé = Button(canvas, text=" / ", font=("Courrier", 23), bg="#0077b6", fg="white")
boutonDivisé.place(x=193, y=62)

boutonEgal = Button(canvas, text=" = ", font=("Courrier", 23), bg="#48cae4", fg="white")
boutonEgal.place(x=126, y=236)

boutonVirgule = Button(canvas, text="  , ", font=("Courrier", 23), bg="#48cae4", fg="white")
boutonVirgule.place(x=63, y=236)

boutonQuitter = Button(canvas, text=" q ", font=("Courrier", 23), bg="red", fg="white", command=Quitter)
boutonQuitter.place(x=189, y=236)

# Nombres

bouton1 = Button(canvas, text=" 1 ", font=("Courrier", 23), bg="black", fg="white", command=Bouton1)
bouton1.place(x=0, y=112)

bouton2 = Button(canvas, text=" 2 ", font=("Courrier", 23), bg="black", fg="white", command=Bouton2)
bouton2.place(x=63, y=112)

bouton3 = Button(canvas, text=" 3 ", font=("Courrier", 23), bg="black", fg="white", command=Bouton3)
bouton3.place(x=126, y=112)

bouton4 = Button(canvas, text=" 4 ", font=("Courrier", 23), bg="black", fg="white", command=Bouton4)
bouton4.place(x=189, y=112)

bouton5 = Button(canvas, text=" 5 ", font=("Courrier", 23), bg="black", fg="white", command=Bouton5)
bouton5.place(x=0, y=112+62)

bouton6 = Button(canvas, text=" 6 ", font=("Courrier", 23), bg="black", fg="white", command=Bouton6)
bouton6.place(x=63, y=112+62)

bouton7 = Button(canvas, text=" 7 ", font=("Courrier", 23), bg="black", fg="white", command=Bouton7)
bouton7.place(x=126, y=112+62)

bouton8 = Button(canvas, text=" 8 ", font=("Courrier", 23), bg="black", fg="white", command=Bouton8)
bouton8.place(x=189, y=112+62)

bouton9 = Button(canvas, text=" 9 ", font=("Courrier", 23), bg="black", fg="white", command=Bouton9)
bouton9.place(x=0, y=236)

# Fonctionnement du résultat

result = 0

output = Label(canvas, text=result, font=("Courrier", 30), bg="cyan", fg="white")
output.place(x=23, y=30)

window.mainloop()
```

I don't know if that is a problem caused by tkinter or not.

Comment: Remember that when `=` is pressed, you need to perform a calculation based on the previously entered operator and two numbers. So you need at least one variable more than you have now.

Comment: You haven't assigned a function to the command option of the *equal* button. So nothing will be performed when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Add the `bt_equal()`

> My calculator doesn't work, it doesn't print the result on the screen.

I had same `Label` widget in my calculator project.

I will use my eight(8) functions to implement your working script.

- Avoid using the wildcard `*`. Use `import tkinter as tk` then use the
  `tk.` prefix for widgets.
- Add four(4) functions for `btn_plus`, `btn_divisor`, `btn_minus` and
  `btn_multiply`. Because of that, it will calculate for you eg:
  `5x5+5/3=10`. Without four functions, you will get bugged eg:
  `5x5+5/3=26.6666...`
- Add this `input_text = tk.StringVar()` and add keyword for `output = tk.Label(canvas, textvariable=input_text,...)`
- Add keyword `command = lambda: btn_click(x)` The **x** denoted from 1 to
  10
  Add keyword command=lambda: btn_plus("x"). The **x** denoted "**+**", "**-**", "*****", "**/**"
- Add the `bt_equal()` to performed operators.
- Also, you may want to add clear `textvariable`. I add `bt_clear()`.
  In case you need this.

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk
 

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Calculatrice")
window.geometry("250x350")
window.configure(bg="cyan")

Canvaswidth = 250
Canvasheight = 350

expression = ""
input_text = tk.StringVar()

def btn_click(item):
    global expression
    expression = expression + str(item)
    input_text.set(expression)

    
def btn_plus(item):
    global expression
    x= (eval(input_text.get()))
    expression = ""
    btn_click(x)
     
    expression += str(item)
    input_text.set(expression)

def btn_divisor(item):
    global expression
    x = (eval(input_text.get()))
    expression = ""
    btn_click(x)
     
    expression += str(item)
    input_text.set(expression)
    
    
def btn_minus(item):
    global expression
    x = (eval(input_text.get()))
    expression = ""
    btn_click(x)
     
    expression += str(item)
    input_text.set(expression)

def btn_multiply(item):
    global expression
    x = (eval(input_text.get()))
    expression = ""
    btn_click(x)
     
    expression += str(item)
    input_text.set(expression)      

def bt_clear(): 
    global expression 
    expression = "" 
    input_text.set("")
 
 
def bt_equal():
    global expression
    result = str(eval(expression))
    input_text.set(result)
    expression = ""
    
def Quitter():
    canvas.forget()
    window.destroy() 

canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width=Canvaswidth, height=Canvasheight, bg="cyan")
canvas.pack()

# Optionnel

remplirBas = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 299, 250, 350, fill="#023e8a")

crédits = tk.Label(canvas, text="Calculatrice créée par Tresda28", font=("Segoe print", 10), bg="#023e8a", fg="#0077b6")
crédits.place(x=15, y=310)

output = tk.Label(canvas, textvariable=input_text,  font=("Courrier", 30), bg="cyan", fg="white")
output.place(x=23, y=30)

# Opérateurs

boutonPlus = tk.Button(canvas, text=" + ", font=("Courrier", 23), bg="#0077b6", fg="white", command=lambda: btn_plus("+"))
boutonPlus.place(x=128, y=0)

boutonMoins = tk.Button(canvas, text=" - ", font=("Courrier", 23), bg="#0077b6", fg="white", command=lambda: btn_minus("-"))
boutonMoins.place(x=192, y=0)

boutonFois = tk.Button(canvas, text=" * ", font=("Courrier", 26), bg="#0077b6", fg="white", command=lambda: btn_multiply("*"))
boutonFois.place(x=128, y=62)

boutonDivisé = tk.Button(canvas, text=" / ", font=("Courrier", 23), bg="#0077b6", fg="white", command=lambda: btn_divisor("/"))
boutonDivisé.place(x=193, y=62)

boutonEgal = tk.Button(canvas, text=" = ", command=lambda: bt_equal(), font=("Courrier", 23), bg="#48cae4", fg="white")
boutonEgal.place(x=126, y=236)

boutonQuitter = tk.Button(canvas, text=" q ", font=("Courrier", 23), bg="red", fg="white", command=Quitter)
boutonQuitter.place(x=189, y=236)

# Nombres

bouton1 = tk.Button(canvas, text=" 1 ", font=("Courrier", 23), bg="black", fg="white", command = lambda: btn_click(1))
bouton1.place(x=0, y=112)

bouton2 = tk.Button(canvas, text=" 2 ", font=("Courrier", 23), bg="black", fg="white", command = lambda: btn_click(2))
bouton2.place(x=63, y=112)

bouton3 = tk.Button(canvas, text=" 3 ", font=("Courrier", 23), bg="black", fg="white", command = lambda: btn_click(3))
bouton3.place(x=126, y=112)

bouton4 = tk.Button(canvas, text=" 4 ", font=("Courrier", 23), bg="black", fg="white", command = lambda: btn_click(4))
bouton4.place(x=189, y=112)

bouton5 = tk.Button(canvas, text=" 5 ", font=("Courrier", 23), bg="black", fg="white", command = lambda: btn_click(5))
bouton5.place(x=0, y=112+62)

bouton6 = tk.Button(canvas, text=" 6 ", font=("Courrier", 23), bg="black", fg="white", command = lambda: btn_click(6))
bouton6.place(x=63, y=112+62)

bouton7 = tk.Button(canvas, text=" 7 ", font=("Courrier", 23), bg="black", fg="white", command = lambda: btn_click(7))
bouton7.place(x=126, y=112+62)

bouton8 = tk.Button(canvas, text=" 8 ", font=("Courrier", 23), bg="black", fg="white", command = lambda: btn_click(8))
bouton8.place(x=189, y=112+62)

bouton9 = tk.Button(canvas, text=" 9 ", font=("Courrier", 23), bg="black", fg="white", command = lambda: btn_click(9))
bouton9.place(x=0, y=236)

bouton0 = tk.Button(canvas, text=" 0 ", font=("Courrier", 23), bg="black", fg="white", command = lambda: btn_click(0))
bouton0.place(x=63, y=236)


window.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

**Noticed**: Those four(4) functions `btn_plus`, `btn_divisor`, `btn_minus` and `btn_multiply` are similar to Microsoft's calculator to update calculated operators.

Answer (score 0):

You have not assigned the `BoutonEgal()` function to the `boutonEgal` button. To do so, you need to add the `command` argument of the `boutonEgal` button. Modified code:

```
boutonEgal = Button(canvas, text=" = ", font=("Courrier", 23), bg="#48cae4", fg="white", command= BoutonEgal) #Add the command argument
boutonEgal.place(x=126, y=236)
```

You haven’t assigned any value to the `result` variable. Its value is always `0`. So, you need to modify your `BoutonEgal()` function to calculate the result. Modified function:

```
def BoutonEgal():
    global opération, nombre, expression
    result = str(eval(expression)) #Add this line
    opération = result
    output.config(text=result)
    window.update()
```

BTW, it’s not considered good naming practice to start variable and function names with capital letters. Naming conventions in python generally use the [snake_case](https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/software-development/programming-naming-conventions-explained#snake-case). So, you should name your functions like, `bouton1()`, `bouton2()` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example that makes heavy use of the [lambda keyword (anonymous functions)](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp). I hope that the comments will make sense.

It looks like you might be having trouble understanding variable scope in Python. [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp) has a tutorial and examples for you that might help.

In this example, a [tkinter StringVar](https://www.askpython.com/python-modules/tkinter/stringvar-with-examples) is used to store the equation. This is not the same as a normal Python variable, so we must use its special set() and get() functions.

When the equals button is pressed, another function is called which gets the equation text and solves it using the [eval()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32642178/what-is-the-tkinter-eval-function) function. If the CLEAR button is pressed, the equation variable is set to a blank string.

This example also has some very basic error handling in case the user does something wrong (blank equation, divide by zero, etc). I have not included your colouring of the buttons - you can do this as a learning exercise.

```
## import tkinter so we can draw a GUI
import tkinter

## initialise the variable 'equation' in the global scope
equation = None

## this is the function that will be called whenever a number of operator button is pressed
def update_equation(operator):
    ## import the global variable 'equation' in to the scope of this function
    global equation
    ## use equation.get() to get the current equation text, then add a space, then add the new 
    ## operator
    equation.set(equation.get() + ' ' + operator)

## this is the function that will be called if the equals button is pressed
def solve_equation():
    ## import the global variable 'equation' in to the scope of this function
    global equation
    ## if the equation is blank...
    if equation == '':
        ## make a blank answer
        answer = ''
    ## if the equation is not blank..
    else:
        ## try to...
        try:
            ## get the equation text with equation.get(), then solve it with eval(), then convert
            ## it to text with str() and set that as the answer
            answer = str(eval(equation.get()))
        ## if an exception occurs (for example, divide by zero)..
        except:
            ## if the answer caused an error to occur, set the answer to 'Error!'
            answer = 'Error!'
    
    ## get the equation text up to the equals sign (if it is there) and set that as the full
    ## equation. if we don't do this, equals signs will keep being added each time you press the
    ## equals button and the equation won't solve
    full_equation = equation.get().split('=')[0]
    
    ## set the equation variable so that it will show the full equation, followed by equals and
    ## a space, and then the answer
    equation.set(full_equation + '= ' + answer)

## make the root window
root = tkinter.Tk()
## give the window a title
root.title('Calculator')
## make a tkinter String variable so that we can store the equation and display it in the GUI
equation = tkinter.StringVar()
## make the equation blank to start
equation.set('')

## make a label to show the equation:
##    - set the textvariable to the equation variable we just made. this means any changes to the
##      equation variable show in the GUI immediately
##    - set the relief to GROOVE so that a border line is shown around the equation area
##    - set the font to 12pt and bold so that it easier to see
##    - in the same line, place it in the GUI using the grid geometry manager at row 0, 
##      column 0. tell it to take up four columns
tkinter.Label(root, textvariable = equation, relief = tkinter.GROOVE, width = 40, font = ('', 12, 'bold')).grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 4)
## make a button for each number
##    - set the text to the number displayed
##    - set the command so that it calls update_equation with the number as the argument. lambda
##      is used to make anonymous functions, which will let you 'snapshot' a variable at the time
##      it is created and pass it to the function
##    - in the same line, place it in the grid using the grid geometry manager at the specified 
##      row and column. set sticky to 'north,east,south,west' so that it expands to fill as much
##      space as possible in that grid position
tkinter.Button(root, text = '1', command = lambda e='1': update_equation(e)).grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = 'news')
tkinter.Button(root, text = '2', command = lambda e='2': update_equation(e)).grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = 'news')
tkinter.Button(root, text = '3', command = lambda e='3': update_equation(e)).grid(row = 1, column = 2, sticky = 'news')
tkinter.Button(root, text = '4', command = lambda e='4': update_equation(e)).grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = 'news')
tkinter.Button(root, text = '5', command = lambda e='5': update_equation(e)).grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = 'news')
tkinter.Button(root, text = '6', command = lambda e='6': update_equation(e)).grid(row = 2, column = 2, sticky = 'news')
tkinter.Button(root, text = '7', command = lambda e='7': update_equation(e)).grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = 'news')
tkinter.Button(root, text = '8', command = lambda e='8': update_equation(e)).grid(row = 3, column = 1, sticky = 'news')
tkinter.Button(root, text = '9', command = lambda e='9': update_equation(e)).grid(row = 3, column = 2, sticky = 'news')
tkinter.Button(root, text = '0', command = lambda e='0': update_equation(e)).grid(row = 4, column = 1, sticky = 'news')

## make a button for each operator. the process is the same as it is for the numbers
tkinter.Button(root, text = '+', command = lambda e='+': update_equation(e)).grid(row = 1, column = 3, sticky = 'news')
tkinter.Button(root, text = '-', command = lambda e='-': update_equation(e)).grid(row = 2, column = 3, sticky = 'news')
tkinter.Button(root, text = 'x', command = lambda e='*': update_equation(e)).grid(row = 3, column = 3, sticky = 'news')
tkinter.Button(root, text = '/', command = lambda e='/': update_equation(e)).grid(row = 4, column = 3, sticky = 'news')

## make a big equals button
##   - this will call the solve_equation function instead.
##   - just like the other buttons, we are placing it in the grid. the only change this time is
##     that we tell it to take up four columns
tkinter.Button(root, text = '=', command = solve_equation).grid(row = 5, column = 0, columnspan = 4, sticky = 'news')

## make a big buton to clear the result
##  - this function demonstrates the lambda keyword again, but this time we use it to call a
##    tkinter function directly, instead of one we have written
tkinter.Button(root, text = 'CLEAR', command = lambda v=equation: v.set('')).grid(row = 6, column = 0, columnspan = 4, sticky = 'news')  

## start the main GUI event loop. this stops the program from exiting until you close it
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work to perform 5x5+5/3=  26.66666....

Comment: That is the expected answer for that equation following BODMAS/PEMDAS: 5x5+5/3=5x5+1.6667=25+1.6667=26.6667 What is the answer you are expecting, and how did you work it out?

Answer (score -1):

Hi I think I know what you're getting at, how about changing the way it works, you could use the `eval()` statement which takes a string and evaluates it. What you can do from there is use a string that gets added to. Here's an example.

```py
x = ""
x += input()
print(eval(x))
```

output:

```
10+10
20
```

Comment: OP's problem is with getting the inputs and displaying the result in a tkinter GUI, so this doesn't address the question. `input` isn't going to capture input from a GUI element.